# Jquery Ajax get request to separated urls in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, html-select

I have the following form:

```
<p>Choose your page:</p>
<form id="ChartsForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <select name="accmenu" id="accmenu" style="width:300px;">
        <?php
        $user_accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts','GET');
        foreach($user_accounts['data'] as $account) {
        ?>
            <option data-description="<?php echo $account['category'] ?>" data-image="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $account['id']; ?>/picture" value="<?php echo $account['id'] ?>"><?php echo $account['name'] ?></options>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <p>Choose your insights:</p>
    <div class="chartsbuttons">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily new likes">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily unlikes">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily page views">
    </div>
</form>
```

which contain a select and for the moment three test submit buttons called: "Daily new likes", "Daily unlikes" and "Daily page views". I use an ajax call like this defined in the submitForm function:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'check.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
        function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }});
    return false;
};
```

to check for now if the selected option value is send to the php script and alert me the response which must be the facebook page id. Here is the php script:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['accmenu'];
?>
```

This is working fine but I will create a php file for each of the submit button to send request to. Example: if I press "Daily new likes" it will send a get request to newlikes.php and if I press "Daily page views" it will send a get request to pageviews.php. I have defined just one form and I would like to keep it that way. How is possible to send to a specific url with JQuery Ajax based on the submit buttons? I have to create a new JavaScript function for each of the inputs? What about the form, I have to create new ones? If I create new ones the select will not be available to each of them right? I really need guidance because I am stuck at this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP, you should not need to set up 3 separate files to perform the requests unless you really want to. You should be able to use your existing function with a few modifications to perform the heavy lifting, but here is a modification that calls a different file based on parameter specified:

```
function submitForm(action) {
    $.ajax({type:'GET', url: action + '.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
        function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }});
    return false;
};
```

Next you would assign some attribute to the buttons, and bind the click event to trigger your function:

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily new likes" data-action="new_likes">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("input[type='submit']", "#ChartsForm").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  submitForm($(this).attr("data-action"));
});
```